# Testing in Zap, suggests me to fix SQL Lite when I'm using Postgres as my database

Tags: zap

I Have built my backend in Laravel 8+ and PostgreSQL. While testing my API for security fixes, I get the security error of possible SQLi error through SQL Lite and Mongo DB. Since I have not used any of the above databases, should I worry about it much?

Comment: Please include detail from the report indicating the concern that ZAP has raised. 

For example "fix SQL Lite" does not give enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Well you haven't provided much detail.

You should investigate the finding and see if you can re-create the issue.

Chances are it's a false positive based on system load/performance.

Without further details we're just guessing though.